# Load more DLL files into 1 assembly object in .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflection

let's say I have 5 DLL files that are each a partial class, that they should form together... Is there a way I could load these 5 files into 1 assembly object ?

Comment: What do you mean "5 DLL files that are each a partial class"? You want to get a single .DLL with 5 classes or a single class?

Comment: No, put all the files together in a single assembly. There's no way you could have a *partial* classes strewn amongst multiple DLLs unless you wrote the code yourself. If so, you made a mistake. Easy enough to fix, add all the code files to a blank project and re-compile.

Comment: 1st DLL
Partial class MyClass
'code
End Class

2nd DLL
Partial class MyClass
'other code
End class


etc

Comment: Right, bruno, that's what we're saying. You can't spread a partial class across multiple DLLs. A partial class must be defined in the same assembly, the only thing that makes it `partial` is that it can be defined in multiple files. You need to move all of those code files into the same project and recompile as a single DLL before you can use them.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to spread a partial class across more than one DLL.  Putting 5 classes in one DLL is quite possible, just keep adding classes to your project.  Don't start looking at ILMerge until you sorted this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to merge all assemblies into one. If that's not what you're asking, you cannot have partitions of the same class distributed accross multiple assemblies. The only workaround that I know of is using [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).